# Multiple wives in Chazal

Tags: marriage

Is anyone aware of any of the Tanaim or Amoraim who had more than one wife (at the same time)? Not just technically married, but actually living together as husband and wife (or wives). I was once told that you will not find any that did.

Comment: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40738&st=&pgnum=62&hilite=

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26586/what-were-the-marriage-rights-of-the-temporary-wives-of-rav-and-rav-nachman

Comment: Rav Tarfon married three hundred women to feed them terumah http://mi.yodeya.com/q/55134

Comment: 4 ,more is not recommended

Comment: @kouty the assumption is that was advice for the layman and no upstanding men like tanaim and amoraim practiced actual polygamy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Hebrew Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%94#cite_ref-6) says that

> לא ידוע על תנאים או על אמוראים שהיו נשואים לשתי נשים יחד. על פי זה,
>   הסיק הרב [ראובן מרגליות](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%95%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA) שריבוי נשים, גם אם הוא מותר - איננו מומלץ,
>   ואף מגונה.‏
>
> We do not find any Tanaim or Amoraim married to two wives together and
>   Rav Reuven Margulies concludes that multiple wives even if permitted
>   is not advised and is even unpleasant.

This is cited to "עוללות, מוסד הרב קוק, תש"ז עמ' 13."

He does not mention the Yerushalmi Yevomos mentioned [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/55134/5323) and in several of the comments.

Comment: The yerushalmi I referenced is clearly not the ordinary case of multiple wives

Comment: +1 IIRC Rabbi Margolios mentions a Yalkut Shimoni about Elkana that implies marring multiple women was not an upstanding thing to do.

Answer (score 5):

No, I’m not aware of such a citation. But I have two tangential observations I’d like to make.

1. *Chazal* clearly talk about polygamy as if it were a going concern. This is not dispositive; they often talk about many areas of *halacha* as if these areas had current application regardless of whether they did in fact have current application. Still it’s interesting to see discussion of polygamy in which nobody suggests that polygamy is a dead letter. At Succah 27a4 someone asks R’ Eliezer about the correct way to fulfill the Succah obligations given that he (the one asking the question) has one wife in Tiberius and one in Tzipori; questions about polygamy arise at Kiddushin 50b3, Bava Basra 143a2, etc. In Tractate Yevamos (as for example Yevamos 65a3) the topic arises again and again; one of the major topics of the tractate is whether a given man and woman should perform a [levirate marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levirate_marriage), given various relationships among the parties that can include the other wives of the deceased or surviving brother.
2. Where rabbis mention their own wives, the Gemara seems uncurious about the order of the marriages or how they ended. For example, we’re told (Avodah Zarah 20a3 #28, cf. Nedarim-50b Rishoinim) that Rabbi Akiva married the former Mrs. Turnus Rufus. The Gemara doesn’t seem to mind that elsewhere in Shas R’ Akiva married [Rachel] the daughter of a [Bar] Kalbua Savua (Nedarim 50a1, Kesubos 62b, Chagigah 12a5).

But I definitely agree that what's more striking is the seeming *scarcity* of polygamy during a period before the famous ban, with only a very few references in such an enormous record of life in the age of Chazal.

P.S. Some of my page numbers are ArtScroll-style, in which style the Vilna page number is followed by a digit reflecting the number of pages of translation. For example, Succah 27a4 refers to Vilna Succah 27a, but page 4 in ArtScroll's translation of that page. This specificity might sometimes be useful even to someone uninterested in ArtScroll's translation, as a way of identifying a place on the daf.

Comment: "The Gemara doesn’t seem to mind that elsewhere in Shas R’ Akiva married [Rachel] the daughter of a [Bar] Kalbua Savua" Maybe its just two accounts. How do we know that the authors of either story know about the other?

Comment: @mevaqesh I agree that we don't know whether the authors knew of both events. You might think that the details of R' Akiva's family life would have been better-known to Chazal (in that generation and later ones) than they are to me, but that would be just a hunch.

Comment: It's not at all unreasonable to expect r Akiva only took a second wife after his first one died, since he was apparently so old https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82954/759

Comment: @Double AA♦ I have no objection to that supposition. I was just commenting that although Moses613 and I are curious about the question, the Gemara seems not to be. It seems to me that if you found out that a married man had married again, it would be totally natural to ask "Isn't he already married?"

Comment: @Double AA In other words, our response ("Isn't he already married?") is natural because in our world (at the moment) polygamy is not normal. In a world in which polygamy was normal you might expect people to do what the Gemara does: ascribe more than one wife to the same man without surprise.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind. Polygamy was probably a "privilege" of the wealthy, which is not exactly the set that most of chazal were in.

Comment: @Moses613 Actually R' Akiva was very wealthy late in his life, and some other sages were wealthy too. But the conversation is being walked farther and farther out on the limb. The two-wives-no-problem attitude suggests (to me) of a world of polygamy, but whether it also reflects an allowance for the wealthy is stretching the point too far beyond the available evidence, I think.

Comment: "scarcity of polygamy"  "privilege of the wealthy"...then, as now, after marriage their tastes seem to magically lean towards the expensive side... :)

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that there  was such an instance . In Yevamos 15a that Abba had two wives.

תָּא שְׁמַע: מַעֲשֶׂה בְּבִתּוֹ שֶׁל רַבָּן גַּמְלִיאֵל שֶׁהָיְתָה נְשׂוּאָה לְאַבָּא אָחִיו, וּמֵת בְּלֹא בָּנִים, וְיִיבֵּם רַבָּן גַּמְלִיאֵל אֶת צָרָתָהּ. וְתִסְבְּרָא, רַבָּן גַּמְלִיאֵל מִתַּלְמִידֵי בֵּית שַׁמַּאי הוּא?
The Gemara suggests:

Come and hear an incident involving Rabban Gamliel’s daughter, who was married to Abba, his brother, and Abba died childless, and Rabban Gamliel entered into levirate marriage with her rival wife.

Comment: Is this Abba a Tanna?

Comment: His brother was

Comment: But the question was if a Tanna had two wives at the same time.